# How to checkout SVN repository to the live site for the first time?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have a subversion repository for my project. Now I need to make my project live. I have FTP details for my live server. So my question is: How do I check my project out for the first time? 
Do I need to install anything before I can use `svn co "repo_url"` command on the live server?

Answer (score 7):

Two thing, (this is the policy we follow. So just suggestions)

1. Do not install SVN on your server. Rather, checkout on a build server/machine. Build or package whatever you want to go to the live server with all production parameters. Then Copy (scp, upload) the built package to live server under your server's deployment directory.
2. Since you are going to deploy this code, not further development is going to be in the checked-out stuff. So, export instead of checkout. `svn export repo_url` -- this will do clean checkout.

Yes, you need Subversion command-line client or any other SVN client like Tortoise SVN.

see here http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Hope this helps.

---

After much discussion over *SVN as release tool: yay or nay?* with @Nathan Kidd, I still disagree that SVN is the right tool. It is a version control tool not a deployment/upload tool. Nathan does have solid points but I prefer convention over configuration.

However, one interested in deployment/release cycle can find this slide-show http://www.slideshare.net/wakaleo/automated-deployment-with-maven-going-the-whole-nine-yards helpful. This presentation takes step-by-step process of building the code, releasing the package and deploying. Introduces appropriate tools (many of them are Java specific but worth going over even if you're doing non-Java stuffs) for any given task. I hope this will be helpful.

You can always develop your own custom release process if you have reasons to justify it.

Comment: What does this achieve? It means you loose efficient updates, and the ability to easily see if anyone has changed something in the production machine (svn status).  I think the sane thing is to making tags/branches for production and checking those out.

Comment: @Nathan Kidd prod release is a critical event. You do not do it daily. The idea is to minimize loose strings. So, when you release you precisely know what code is going there and there is no accidental updates. Plus, in most cases, you have prod setup differently than local/test builds. Your parameters like DB connections are different. So, you not want people making changes there. For that, there is a concept of spot-release. And, you are right, when you say, creating tag for release. You must create a release tag. Tag is like a milestone. You don't fiddle into server code by SSHing contd...

Comment: contd... you look into tag, and see what's wrong with prod and where. And then you create a branch off that tag and fix the issue do a spot release. The same way you did earlier. This process does look cumbersome and _old fashioned_ believe me it gives so much confidence during release and you provide solid response on the questions like what if release went wrong. The whole idea is exclusiveness. The bigger the organization the more loose ends you find. (multiple apps and services relying on each-other) In those cases, this definitely makes sense.

Comment: @Nishant, I'm still not sold. :)  What we're talking about is a technical method of pushing changes to production.  "Accidental updates", "prod set up differently", "confidence" are merely semantics you apply to your process.  You feel comfortable, sure, but I'm arguing there's no technical reason for that.  You could lock down your process and tag/branch permissions to get the same comfort levels and get the benefits I mentioned at first.

Comment: In fact, you should feel more comfortable doing `svn update`.  Your response to "production is broken" is first, `svn status`, OK, confirmed production files exactly match our tag, now go check the code. Instead of "let me diff production tree with source tarball, ok, that matches, now let me diff svn tag with source tarball", ok that matches too, now go check the code.

Comment: @Nathan Kidd Release is a _process_, go with one that suits you best. Technically, there is nothing wrong with your approach. If you are checking out tag. You are stuck at dead-end. Tags are commanly not modified (SVN lets you update with a warning). If you do build with a branch, you need to remember the revision number to do rollback. So, `svn up` is not that helpful. If you are OK with using your deployment server/s as build server/s that's fine as long as you have one server. If you have more than one, you either perform repeated build on each...

Comment: .. servers or you somehow upload (scp, upload) to other servers. You are essentially saying that you want to convert one or all the deployment servers into build server. Nothing wrong with that. It's just a process. I find single build server that has all the responsibility of single click build, upload and deploy more robust and easy.

Comment: @Nishant, Using `svn up` as a deployment method has nothing to do with tags being a "dead end" or "converting deployment servers into build server".  Again, as a method of pushing changes to a server, and verifying what is on the server, svn has some nice features.  All the issues you are bringing up are merely details of the process that you can do right regardless of the method you push changes.

Comment: @Nathan Kidd (1)If you want SVN to be a tool that transports your production release tar/jar/war -- it's wrong. It's for source revisions not for binary storage. (2) Tags are dead-ends, you loose efficient update. (3) Even if you use SVN, you will have to "pull" code on each server. Opposite to having one build server that checksout and "pushes" release build to all the servers and deploys it there on issue of single click/command. Not sure if I can explain more.

Comment: It looks like I'm thinking "website" as in "many pages of static HTML, maybe with PHP, etc", whereas you are perhaps thinking of "war file deployed to a servlet container"?  I don't know the details of your particular situation, but in the general case think outside the "just wrong" box a little: svn can a perfect solution for deployment. :)

Comment: @Nathan Kidd :) may be we are seeing the two faces of build and release. But, in that case, wouldn't RSYNC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync be a better option?